How do I uninstall interactions.py module that I install from github?
I am currently coding a discord.py bot and recently installed a interactions.py module using the following command line
pip install git+https://github.com/interactions-py/interactions.py.git@unstable

I tried to uninstall it using the following 4 commands; all of which failed and resulted in an error.
pip uninstall git+https://github.com/interactions.py/interactions.py.git@unstable
pip uninstall git
pip uninstall interactions.py.git
pip uninstall interactions.py.git@unstable

How do I uninstall it as it is interfering with my other code?

pip uninstall interactions.py

You can check with what name the package has got installed with pip list.

More specifically pip list | grep interaction if using linux.

When you run pip install you install a package from an external source so in the command line you name that source: a file, a list of files, a (list of) requirements files, a list of package name (in the latter case the external sources are preconfigured list of indices with the default index being PyPI.org), a VCS repository (in your case a branch of a GitHub repository).
When you run pip uninstall you uninstall a locally installed package. There're no external sources, only local packages. So the command line must list names of packages to uninstall. The name of your package is interactions.py (pyproject.toml, setup.py) so the command line should be
pip uninstall interactions.py

